# C#: How to get value from second column in datatable corresponding to the first column value?

Tags: c#

I already established the connection with database using OleDB, and I have two working textboxes with autocomplete from the first column (Model) of the datatable:

```
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Model FROM GPU", conn);
            OleDbCommand cmb = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Model FROM CPU", conn);
            OleDbCommand cmg = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TDP FROM GPU", conn);
            OleDbCommand cmc = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TDP FROM CPU", conn);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmb.ExecuteReader();
           AutoCompleteStringCollection mygpu = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
           AutoCompleteStringCollection mycpu = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
           while (dr.Read()) { mygpu.Add(dr.GetString(0));  }
           while (dr2.Read()) { mycpu.Add(dr2.GetString(0));  }
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mygpu;
            textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycpu;
```

The thing is I just want to summarize values from the second column (TDP) corresponding to the values from the first column (Model) which I picked in textboxes. I'm stuck. Any advice is appreciated

[database example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W578n.png)

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow!, i don;t see any second column both sql retrieves just one column? are we missing something?

Comment: @coder_b Sorry, I called the second column, and I can read the values from it, but I don't know how to summarize them according to the picked values from the first column